# Image Gallery - Slider

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I developed an image gallery. In a main box (large box) I introduce the first image of the array, the rest are arranged horizontally below that image.

Is there a way to get the big box to function as an image slider?

At this point try to apply, however I have some problems :( the secondary images do not appear below the main one, nor is the slider working correctly, when I move to the second image, all the others are loaded.

I chose to use * ngFor to load secondary images, in case I can have an array with indeterminate quantities of images.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbtt1k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**CODE**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="drop">
        <div class="abc">
            <img class="img-fluid Images" [src]="images[0].img" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let img of images | slice:1" cdkDrag>

                <img class="img-thumbnail" [src]="img.img" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- -------------------------------SLIDER----------- -->


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
                <div class="drop">
                    <div class="abc">
                        <ng-template ngbSlide>
                            <img [src]="images[0].img" alt="Random first slide">
                        </ng-template>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ng-template ngbSlide>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let img of images | slice:1" cdkDrag>

                            <img class="img-thumbnail" [src]="img.img" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          </div>
                        </div>
                </ng-template>
            </ngb-carousel>
        </div>
```

**What I want with the functional slider**

I intend that when clicking on the buttons on the slider it will display the secondary images (the images shown below the main image)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use [corousel-Api](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api) to get change event.

corousel emit **slide** event when image is change(automatic or via button)
so you have to add an event to corousel change i have added change($event) to (slide) output.

```
<ngb-carousel id="carousel" #carouse *ngIf="data" (slide)="change($event)" >
  <ng-template *ngFor="let imgIdx of data; let i = index" [id]="i" ngbSlide>
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img [src]="imgIdx.image" [alt]="">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>{{imgIdx.head}}</h3>
      <p>{{imgIdx.data}}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>

<div *ngFor="let imgIdx of belowImageData; let i = index" style="width:80px" >
 <img class="col-sm" [src]="imgIdx.image" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

then in chnage event i have updated belowImageData array according to image loded in upper corousel.

```
  constructor(){
  this.belowImageData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
  this.belowImageData.splice(0,1);
  }

  change(data){
    console.log(data.current)
    this.belowImageData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    this.belowImageData.splice(data.current, 1);
  }
```

you can also add this line to pause automatic slide

```
this.carousel.pause();
```

i have developed a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3njhvn) for you(without proper css).

Comment: Tahnk you ! Thats perfect !